# UWP MapControl, MapProjection for non-geographic images

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-maps

I have a UWP MapControl with a CustomMapTileDataSource to display very high resolution 2D images, not geographical data. I managed to provide my own tiles as described in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/maps-and-location/overlay-tiled-images, including the steps of the section "Replace the default map".

I use the MapProjection WebMercator, but depending on the location and the zoom level, it deforms/bends the rendering as if we were looking at a sphere.

This is with a zoom level < 5:
[image: Normal]

This is with a zoom level >= 5:
[image: Deformed]

Of course the other choice (Globe) is totally inadequate for my application. Instead I would need a very basic flat projection (no deformation). Is it possible?

Comment: In general, it will render flat projection, it may the WebMercator service cause this issue, could you share your code or  Web-Mercator service, I need reproduce this issue.

Comment: Yes, thank you. You will find a quick prototype on https://github.com/gil-c/UWP_Map_proto

Comment: Yep, I run above sample and it works, but it only contains red and green flat tiles.

Comment: Correct, this is just a little demo but the problem is visible when you zoom in with the mouse wheel, especially near the black borders. I updated the repo with 2 screenshots to illustrate the issue.

Comment: Ok, please share the repro screenshot in above case update.

Comment: I got it, it's by design,  Mercator projection significantly distorts scale and area (particularly near the poles),The spherical projection causes approximately 0.33% scale distortion in the Y direction, which is not visually noticeable.For more please refer[Bing Maps Tile System](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bingmaps/articles/bing-maps-tile-system) document

Comment: Do you know if we can get rid of this projection in order to use the component for non-geographic images?

Comment: As far as I know, there is no such way could avoid using Mercator  projection in uwp map control.